# Delphi - DBGrid does not display UTF8 calculated field 

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, firebird2.5, tdbgrid, fibplus

I have a TDBGrid linked to a TDataSource with a TFibDataSet behind. On the OnCalcFields of the dataset I'm trying to add the string 'Russisch (русский)'.

```
procedure TForm1.pFIBDataSet1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  DataSource1.DataSet.FieldByName('Language').AsString := ('Russisch (русский)');
```

The problem is that in the grid the result is displayed as :Russisch(????????)

```
 DataSource1.DataSet.FieldByName('Language').AsWideString :=('Russisch (русский)');
```

has the same result

FibDataBase component has ConnectParams.Charset set to UTF-8. Also I set in the DBParams value `lc_ctype=UTF8`.

What I'm doing wrong here?

LE: [Delphi XE, Firebird and UTF8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892779/delphi-xe-firebird-and-utf8) - this does not solve my problem.

LE1: Problem occurs only with calculated fields. Live data 'Russisch (русский)' is displayed correctly.

Comment: Does this happen only for calculated fields or with live data as well?

Comment: I've made a test now, and it happens only with calculated fields. If live data is ''Russisch (русский)' is displayed correctly.

Comment: I don't have access to Delphi XE at the moment. Look at the definition of `AsString`. Is it `AnsiString`?

Comment: I have tried to make it AsWideString and the result is the same

Comment: If you use persistent fields, make sure you have it defined as T(FIB)WideStringField field instead of TStringField.

Comment: For the persistent fields this is not a problem. 'Russisch (русский)' is displayed correctly. My problem is on the calculated fields.

Comment: Is your unit file saved as `unicode` itself? I mean, what does `ShowMessage('Russisch (русский)');` display?

Comment: Did you define your calculated field as `string` or `WideString`? Note that when you create a `string` field using the buil-in field creator of `TDataSet`, it's not `UTF`.

Comment: iMan Biglari  - post it as answer

Comment: "Persistent fields" not means physical fields from your database. They just are explicitly defined/created in your class instead of dynamic gathering and creation. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526832/code-to-create-persistent-field-components-associated-with-tdataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you made the same mistake I always make. When you create a field like this:

[image]

it's `ANSI`. You have to select `WideString` for it to be unicode:

[image]

Comment: Basically that means there is a cruel bug in FIB (and was it FIB+ as tagged ? arent FIB+ classes tagged prefixed TpFIB... ?)

Comment: You copied my answer in comments ;)

Comment: @Marcodor I just added pictures to your comment ;)

Comment: @Arioch'The the bug is in the logic behind the "New Field" window. It still treats `string` as `AnsiString` and not as `string`

Comment: Why not ? Backward compatibility and such.
The bug is conversion lost when converting UnicodeString constant into AnsiString field type.